# Programmable way to manage standalone databases on Heroku Postgres

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Is there any programmable way to manage standalone databases on Heroku Postgres?  Although it provides a nice web UI for it, but it’s not programmable (at least without any hack).  Heroku seems to likely provide HTTP API or such thing for it, but I couldn’t find it.

Comment: what kind of management work do you want to do specifically?

Comment: @kch Forking, following, upgrading plan and so on…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is "no". Longer answer is "hopefully in the near future, but we don't have an ETA".

Answer (score 1):

Heroku Postgres has an API accessible via [command-line tools](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#using-the-cli) as well as the simple web-based UI.

You can hack the [Ruby client code](https://github.com/heroku/heroku) as well if you feel like.

Comment: Unfortunately Heroku offers CLI only for database addon (for apps), and it can’t be used for standalone databases.

Comment: You are right, didn't catch that. It would be nice if Heroku provided some API support for the standalone DBs.